# vba- compare string to Worksheet name

Tags: string, vba, string-comparison

Sorry, but i have a problem comparing to Strings and I just can not figure out what is wrong.

```
For I = 3 To WS_Count

    If "*rojekt*" = Worksheets(I).Name Then
    Set rng = Worksheets("Übersicht").Range("A2" & I - 1)
    rng.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Range("A2").Value
    End If

    Next I
```

It doesn't through any errors, but I want that the if statement checks if the String is part of the worksheets name and then do sth. in that ws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
if Worksheets(I).Name Like "*rojekt*" Then
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score -1):

You need to replace this line:

```
If "*rojekt*" = Worksheets(I).Name Then
```

with this:

```
If InStr(1, Worksheets(i).Name, "rojekt", vbTextCompare) Then
```

Comment: thanks, that would work, but i just want to compare if  "rojekt" is a part of the Worksheets Name @mielk

Comment: I know, and this is the easiest way to do this in VBA.